# How can I retrieve,add data using Quickbase API and javascript

Tags: javascript, quickbase

I am very new to Quickbase.
I want to query the quickbase using javascript to get a table records and also insert to it.

How should I do this?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

To improve @rtpHarry's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29387494/3629804), the JavaScript SDK he is referencing has seen better days. It hasn't been updated in 2 years, and doesn't work in IE11.

Now this is a shameless plug, full disclosure, I am the author of this module;

But [Node-QuickBase](https://github.com/tflanagan/node-quickbase) is much, much easier to use and works both in the browser and on the server - no code change.

Here is an example:

Within Nodejs:

```
var QuickBase = require('quickbase');

var quickbase = new QuickBase({
    realm: 'www',
    appToken: '*****'
});

quickbase.api('API_Authenticate', {
    username: '*****',
    password: '*****'
}).then(function(result){
    return quickbase.api('API_DoQuery', {
        dbid: '*****',
        clist: '3.12',
        options: 'num-5'
    }).then(function(result){
        return result.table.records;
    });
}).map(function(record){
    return quickbase.api('API_EditRecord', {
        dbid: '*****',
        rid: record[3],
        fields: [
            { fid: 12, value: record[12] }
        ]
    });
}).then(function(){
    return quickbase.api('API_DoQuery', {
        dbid: '*****',
        clist: '3.12',
        options: 'num-5'
    });
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Within the Browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="quickbase.browserify.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var quickbase = new QuickBase({
        realm: 'www',
        appToken: '*****'
    });

    quickbase.api('API_Authenticate', {
        username: '*****',
        password: '*****'
    }).then(function(result){
        return quickbase.api('API_DoQuery', {
            dbid: '*****',
            clist: '3.12',
            options: 'num-5'
        }).then(function(result){
            return result.table.records;
        });
    }).map(function(record){
        return quickbase.api('API_EditRecord', {
            dbid: '*****',
            rid: record[3],
            fields: [
                { fid: 12, value: record[12] }
            ]
        });
    }).then(function(){
        return quickbase.api('API_DoQuery', {
            dbid: '*****',
            clist: '3.12',
            options: 'num-5'
        });
    }).then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin you need to [set up a user in QuickBase](http://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/index.html#usersetup.html%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Overview%7C_____2).

In order for you to use the API [you need to have a developer key](http://www.quickbase.com/api-guide/index.html#authentication_and_secure_access.html%3FTocPath%3DAPI%2520Overview%7C_____3).

There is a JavaScript SDK that you can use which is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/QuickbaseAdmirer/Quickbase-JavaScript-SDK/blob/master/QuickBaseClient.js). This will shield you from the details of the API.

However, this doesn't let you use this inside any random webpage if that's what you're attempting:

> HTML pages using QuickBaseClient.js must be hosted within QuickBase
>   applications as file attachments or as text (code) pages because web
>   browsers only allow JavaScript code to access the web site the
>   JavaScript originated from.

If you do want do that then [there are workarounds](https://quickbase-community.intuit.com/questions/154419-does-the-quickbase-javascript-sdk-work-outside-of-quickbase).